# Do we allow upload the two certificates with same SubjectDN to the same trust-store in Java keystore

Tags: java, key, store

Do we allow upload the two certificates with same SubjectDN to the same trust-store in java keystore?. Any RFC reference we have which says this is not allowed?.
We have Certificate authority which can issue certificates with same SubjectDN and overlapping validity. Do we allow the upload of these certificates to same  trust store and how does the application choose the valid certificate from the 2 same certificates(as both certificates will have same subject DN)

We tried looking at the RFC and implementation for this

Answer (score 0):

What you 'allow' is up to you, but entries in a Java keystore are distinguished by the 'alias' name you assign to them.  If you want to have different entries with the same subject, you can.

[Documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/security/KeyStore.html)

> Each entry in a keystore is identified by an "alias" string. In the
> case of private keys and their associated certificate chains, these
> strings distinguish among the different ways in which the entity may
> authenticate itself. For example, the entity may authenticate itself
> using different certificate authorities, or using different public key
> algorithms.

Comment: In case of a TLS handshake, how does it identify which certificate to present as both certificate have the same subject DN ? How do we select the required certificate

Comment: Both certificates are signed by a same Certificate authority and same public key

Comment: I imagine you write the code to do what you want.  You asked whether you are "allowed" to do this; you have not indicated any reason to **want** to do it.